# Интеграция Web Speech API и Electron JS

Tags: javascript, html, electron

В общем разрабатываю приложение на `Electron JS` и мне нужно совместить данный фреймворк с `Web Speech API`, не доходя даже до реализации логики при простом подключении через `html` у меня просто не работает он. Вот тестовый код.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,400;0,500;1,600&family=Nova+Square&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="speech">Empty</p>
    <p>Current theme source: <strong id="theme-source">System</strong></p>

    <button id="toggle-dark-mode">Switch theme</button>

    <button id="learnLang">Click</button>

    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
    <script src="./listener/activate.js"></script>

    <script>
      let SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
      const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
      recognition.lang = 'ru-Ru'
  
      const button = document.getElementById('learnLang');
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          document.getElementById('speech').innerText = `Default Language: ${recognition.lang}`;
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Знаю что код абсолютно безсмысленный, но он мне нужен был чтобы просто проверить работает ли (нет). Нашел в интернете что у самих `Electron` есть своя библиотека похожая на `Web Speech API`, но данная библиотека не дает все возможности, которые мне нужны. Также где-то нашел что данная проблема решается добавлением `webSecurity: false` в

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
width: 580,
height: 630,
title: 'JarvisAI',
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  webSecurity: false
}
})
```

В итоге тоже не помогло.

Comment: Вы уверены, что свойство recognition.lang можно задавать и читать? Я вот что-то не помню. Лучше проверить работу на том, как реально распознаётся речь.

Comment: Да, я уверен так как я создавал просто `index.html` чистый и там этот код работал